# How to get the column No and cell no of the sap.ui.table.Table in sap ui5?

Tags: sapui5

I have cell oh sap.m.Button on press event i want to know which cell and row no button is clicked can any one help me out.

Comment: jsbin link is given below please help

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wucufeqiyi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`indexOfRow`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#indexOfRow) you will get the row's index in which clicked button is placed.

According to me, there is no need to find-out column's index as it will be same for every button.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zeqofok/edit?html,output) is demo.

Answer (score 2):

// View

```
   <Table cellClick="onPress"></Table>
```

// Controller

```
onPress : function(oEvent) {
        this.showObject(oEvent.getParameters());
},

showObject : function(oParameters) {
    yourTableObject = ..... 2 do
    var rowIndex = oParameters.rowIndex;
    var colIndex = oParameters.columnIndex;
    var sPath = yourTableObject.getContextByIndex(rowIndex).sPath;
    var oDataSelect = yourTableObject.getContextByIndex(rowIndex).oModel.getProperty(sPath);

 }
```

If you want to klick on the Icon it would be

```
onPressYourIcon : function(oEvent) {
   var oItem = oEvent.getSource(); // <-- this is what you Need, the clicked item
   var sPath = oItem.getBindingContext().sPath;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it will work any where you click on the cell but i need to click specific to icon only...so on icon click can we do some thing similar

Comment: i added the item click :) then you have to find out which Icon it is via Id or somehow via binding context, you cannot find out "in which row/column of my table is this Icon"